# get select options from php in x editable

Tags: php, jquery, x-editable

I am using x editable for inline editing.

**JQUERY**

```
$('#status').editable({
  value: 2,
  source: [
  {value: 1, text: 'Active'},
  {value: 2, text: 'Blocked'},
  {value: 3, text: 'Deleted'}
  ]
});
```

This one is running fine. But the problem is, I want to get source options from `php`. For that I have an array.

**PHP**

```
$php_array = Array ( [MOBILE_TOPUP] => MOBILE_TOPUP
                     [PICKUP] =>PICKUP
                     [DELIVERY] => DELIVERY
                     [BANK_DEPOSIT] => BANK_DEPOSIT )
```

I tried with by passing below variable in source but it's not working:

```
var json_array = <?=json_encode($php_array)?>;
```

How can I achieve this? Do I need to change array structure in `PHP`? Thanks for any help!

Comment: That array is not a valid PHP array. [See here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-96)

Comment: I did just `print_r` and post it here. that's y..

Comment: Ah.. then why did you have a title of "PHP" and then start with a variable in code then paste a print output of it?... It's either code or output. Not a mixture of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to change array structure as below :

```
$php_array = Array ( 
        array('value' => 1, 'text' => 'Active'),
        array('value' => 2, 'text' => 'Blocked'),
        array('value' => 3, 'text' => 'Deleted'),
);

var json_array = '<?=json_encode($php_array)?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use PHP inside JS, better to make an ajax call. This feature is built into x-editable if you use the `source` option with a string like so:

```
$('#status').editable({
  value: 2,
  source: 'mypage.php'
});
```

Comment: ok. so, in `mypage.php` I need to just `print_r` array. right?